# Reload activity from same activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I wonder if this is possible, the truth I imagine it must be a bad practical but only to test some things. I would like to call the same activity from itself, not if I explain.

Call to Activity A from Activity A

what I get is clean all sight. I've tried calling the method `onResume`, `onRestart` but I can not get it to work, for some strange reason the application stops working.

Nor I can see the error, since USB have connected the Code bar reader and not the device connected to the computer to view the log.

Comment: By using startActivity() you surely can start another activity of the same class. Do you want to achieve something else?

Comment: @EdwardvanRaak edit it jajaja

Comment: As well? startActivity method call? @AlexanderKulyakhtin

Comment: Rusheel Jain has given that answer already. You have to find a way to get the logcat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the best way to refresh your activity:

```
public void refresh() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

***EDIT 06.11.2021***
Kotlin way to refresh activity

```
private fun refresh() {
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, YourActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use intents.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
startactivity(intent);
finish(); // assuming you wish to kill your previous instance of the activity
```

Comment: If it stops working then collect the logcat. Disconnect your reader after the crash, start Android Monitor and connect your phone. The phone will probably give you the logcat.

Comment: what is the error? 
did you changed that A.class to your Activity's  name?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),YourActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: A few words how your code solves the problem described in the question and what it does would go a long way.